# Problem counting activities and updating column in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have a input where I have like 16 columns, I'm trying to count the rows that I get in my output, so I can find the last row that contains the "BIDGROUP" element inside and place the count in its seventh column, an example:

INPUT:

```
"131594", "", "BIDGROUP", 1, 0, 0, 2, "", 0:00, 0:00, 01JAN2009, 01JAN2009, 01JAN2009, 01JAN2009, false, 0,
"131594", "AWARD", "UNTOUCHABLE", 1, 1, 0, 1, "", 0:00, 0:00, 10JUN2014, 13JUN2014 23:59, 01JAN2009, 01JAN2009, false, 100,
"131594", "AWARD", "ADVANCED_TRIP", 1, 2, 0, 0, "740025Jun2014,705406Jun2014,737722Jun2014,696130Jun2014", 0:00, 0:00, 01JAN2009, 01JAN2009, 01JAN2009, 01JAN2009, false, 15,
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
"131594", "", "BIDGROUP", 1, 0, 0, 5, "", 0:00, 0:00, 01JAN2009, 01JAN2009, 01JAN2009, 01JAN2009, false, 0,
"131594", "AWARD", "UNTOUCHABLE", 1, 1, 0, 1, "", 0:00, 0:00, 10JUN2014, 13JUN2014 23:59, 01JAN2009, 01JAN2009, false, 100,
"131594", "AWARD", "TRIP_ID", 1, 2, 0, 0, "7400", 0:00, 0:00, 25Jun2014, 01JAN2009, 01JAN2009, 01JAN2009, false, 15,
"131594", "AWARD", "TRIP_ID", 1, 3, 0, 0, "7054", 0:00, 0:00, 06Jun2014, 01JAN2009, 01JAN2009, 01JAN2009, false, 15,
"131594", "AWARD", "TRIP_ID", 1, 4, 0, 0, "7377", 0:00, 0:00, 22Jun2014, 01JAN2009, 01JAN2009, 01JAN2009, false, 15,
"131594", "AWARD", "TRIP_ID", 1, 5, 0, 0, "6961", 0:00, 0:00, 30Jun2014, 01JAN2009, 01JAN2009, 01JAN2009, false, 15,
```

If you see in the input the first row has the element "BIDGROUP", and the seventh column has a count of 2, because there are 3 activities only, and in the output the counter change to 5 because we have 6 activities in total.
My output is almost the same, as I said before I only have to count the rows, I already tried to set a count for all the activities but it didn't work like I expected.
This is my original code that was used without the counter:

```
import sys
import re


lines = []

for line in sys.stdin:
    lines.append(line.strip())

output_lines = []

for line in lines:
    elements = line.split(", ")
    if elements[2] == '"ADVANCED_TRIP"':
        elements[2] = '"TRIP_ID"'
        trip_ids = elements[7].split(",")
        dates = re.findall(r'\d{2}[A-Za-z]{3}\d{4}', line)
        for i, (trip_id, date) in enumerate(zip(trip_ids, dates)):
            trip_id = trip_id.strip('"')
            output_line = elements[:7] + [f'"{trip_id[:4]}"'] + elements[8:]
            output_line[4] = str(int(output_line[4]) + i)
            output_line[10] = date
            output_lines.append(output_line)
    else:
        output_lines.append(elements)

for output_line in output_lines:
    print(", ".join(output_line))
```

And this is the try that I did whit the count of all the activities:

```
import sys
import re

lines = []

for line in sys.stdin:
    lines.append(line.strip())

output_lines = []
total_activity_count = 0
trip_id_activity_count = 0

for line in lines:
    elements = line.split(", ")
    if elements[2] == '"BIDGROUP"':
        total_activity_count += 1
        elements[6] = str(total_activity_count)
        output_lines.append(elements)
    elif elements[2] == '"ADVANCED_TRIP"':
        elements[2] = '"TRIP_ID"'
        trip_ids = elements[7].split(",")
        dates = re.findall(r'\d{2}[A-Za-z]{3}\d{4}', line)
        for i, (trip_id, date) in enumerate(zip(trip_ids, dates)):
            trip_id = trip_id.strip('"')
            output_line = elements[:7] + [f'"{trip_id[:4]}"'] + elements[8:]
            output_line[4] = str(int(output_line[4]) + i)
            output_line[10] = date
            output_lines.append(output_line)
            trip_id_activity_count += 1
    else:
        output_lines.append(elements)
        total_activity_count += 1

for output_line in output_lines:
    print(", ".join(output_line))
```

Anyone have abother idea how could this work?

Comment: have you considered using pandas?

Comment: I forgot to say that I'm learning python still new, I have used the library of pandas, but which function could I use?

Comment: In order to update the activity count in the `BIDGROUP` line, you need to hold the other lines in a list until you get to the end. Then you can get the length of that list, add it to the activity count, and output both the updated `BIDGROUP` line and the following lines.

Comment: I checked how to use pandas, converted the lines into a DataFrame, performed counting and update operations easily, and then saved the results back to a text file or print them in the standard output. But when I try to compile it, the page where I'm doing the challenge doesn't find the pandas library, I don't know if this is how you tried to explain to me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you face is that you can't update the BIDGROUP line until you reach the NEXT BIDGROUP, because you don't know the total activity count.  You're attempting time travel in your code; you're writing `total_activity_count` before it has been computed.  However, since you're holding all of the lines a list, you can just save a reference to the BIDGROUP line, and update it later, like this:

```
import sys
import re

lines = []

for line in sys.stdin:
    lines.append(line.strip())

output_lines = []
total_activity_count = 0
trip_id_activity_count = 0
lastbid = None

for line in lines:
    elements = line.split(", ")
    if elements[2] == '"BIDGROUP"':
        if total_activity_count:
            lastbid[6] = str(total_activity_count)
        total_activity_count = 0
        lastbid = elements
        output_lines.append(elements)
    elif elements[2] == '"ADVANCED_TRIP"':
        elements[2] = '"TRIP_ID"'
        trip_ids = elements[7].split(",")
        dates = re.findall(r'\d{2}[A-Za-z]{3}\d{4}', line)
        for i, (trip_id, date) in enumerate(zip(trip_ids, dates)):
            trip_id = trip_id.strip('"')
            output_line = elements[:7] + [f'"{trip_id[:4]}"'] + elements[8:]
            output_line[4] = str(int(output_line[4]) + i)
            output_line[10] = date
            output_lines.append(output_line)
            trip_id_activity_count += 1
    else:
        output_lines.append(elements)
        total_activity_count += 1

if total_activity_count:
    lastbid[6] = str(total_activity_count)
for output_line in output_lines:
    print(", ".join(output_line))
```

One might ask why you're not using the `csv` module for this, which understands these types of files.

Comment: I´m not using the csv module because I´m doing this on page, where there are some challenges, so they upload the input.
And I tried to do it like you showed me, but I have the same output that I had before, where the count is on 1, did I get it wrong somehow? I´m getting confused so sorry

Comment: WHAT value is 1?  I used your second input (with 6 lines).  I replaced the "5" in the first line with "99", and after I run the code, that value is changed back to 5.

Comment: Python lets you use a string wherever a file can be used, using `io.StringIO`.

Comment: forgive me for not being clear, the value of 1 is given to me in the column of the BIDGROUP element, as if it got stuck in the account, of course I do this with the first input

Comment: I don't understand.   All you mentioned above was the 7th column of the BIDGROUP l line.  You didn't say anything about the other columns.